# Ignore KeyDown if the text of a RichTextBox won't change

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, keydown

I need to determine whether a key, when it is pressed, will change the control's text or not; I need to ignore key presses like `Ctrl+Z` or `Esc`, but I need to know which key was pressed if the text changed.

Is there any way to know that *in* the `KeyDown` event? Currently, I'm using a flag, set on `KeyDown` and checked on `TextChanged`, but I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by `will change the control's text or not;`  If your control's text is changed, the `TextChanged` event will get it.  Is it what @Sriram is saying, looking for `IsControl`?

Comment: Yeah... the problem is that I need to know on KeyDown, before TextChanged resolves

Comment: Earlier I just gave an hint. Now updated my answer. Check if that helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Char.IsControl`

```
private Keys lastKey = Keys.None;
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    lastKey = e.KeyData;
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;//prevent this key press
        Keys pressedKey = this.lastKey;
        //Do your stuff with pressedKey  here
    }
}
```

Comment: my thoughts exactly +1

Comment: @DROPtableusers When I proposed `Char.IsControl` I get a downvote. later removed.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the `KeyPress` event on the text box and if it is a valid key you would set `e.handled = false` and if it was a bad key you would set `e.handled = true`.

example from: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx)

```
private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // The keypressed method uses the KeyChar property to check  
        // whether the ENTER key is pressed.  

        // If the ENTER key is pressed, the Handled property is set to true,  
        // to indicate the event is handled. 
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would work in WPF, but the OP hasnt given any indication thats what he is using.

Comment: Indeed... since I don't know anything about WPF sometimes I become oblivious to the fact that it's out there and a lot of people use it... my bad xD

Comment: very true @paqogomez I was assuming. Are you sure that this wouldn't work with a windows forms text box?

Comment: Ya, `EventArgs` does not have a `handled` property.

Comment: `KeyPressEventArgs` does have a `handled` property though.  I put up an example from msdn.

Answer (score 0):

There are some keys which produce a `Control` char but they also change the text, for example `BackSpace`. They have another difficulty: if the `textbox` is empty, pressing them (for example `BackSpace`) doesn't change the text; so it breaks the previous rule. So `Control` characters are not naive to deal with and build a rule upon.

Moreover, consider `Ctrl + C` or `Shift + Insert` or similar cases. The 'C' key is somehow seductive; it is like pressing '`C`' changes the text but if it was pressed with `'Ctrl'`, it actually didn't change the text. We should check the `Modifiers`.

Perhaps you can find other difficulties to deal with and I think the `flag` approach is good enough.